# Nested Object in Kibana visualize

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have uploaded the JSON file in elasticsearch and my mapping contains of some nested objects.

The problem is that, in Kibana, in visualize I can not see them

This is my mapping:

```
"comments": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "count": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "data": {
            "type":"nested",
            "properties": {
                "created_time": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in kibana when I insert **comments.count** I cannot see any result, but in Discover page, the **comments.count** field is exist!

How can I search for this field?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I found, Kibana can not deal with **nested** or **parent/child**

Answer (score 2):

One person in the GitHub issue was able to get results.

This is the GitHub issue tracking the enhancement for this feature: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084

Others have gone to parent child relationships to solve it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way in Kibana to perform nested queries or nested aggregations.

I have an in progress fork that implements this support. I am in the feedback and bug fixing phase. See the discussion here:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084

Fork is here:
https://github.com/homeaway/kibana/tree/fullNestedSupport

Comment: Thanks a lot ppadovani. I am currently using your fork https://github.com/ppadovani/kibana/tree/nestedAggregations for Nested Aggregation Support. Works like charm.

Comment: @ppadovani The above link is responding with 404

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this to split the response. Logstash has to split the response. Hence use the split filter as mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include_in_parent` flag in the mapping of the nested field as a workaround until it is supported by Kibana.

refer to this [link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084#issuecomment-563066241), for more details.